# Не получается выполнить Linq запрос с GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

Не выходит LINQ запрос с методом `GroupBy`

```
public class ReportDto
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public WordDto[] Words { get; set; }
}

 ReportDto[] qwe = this.context.TestResults
            .Where(r => r.Word.Vocabulary.VocabularyID == id)
            .GroupBy(r => r.Date)
            .Select(r => new ReportDto
            {
                Date = r.Key,
                Words = r.Select(re => new WordDto
                {
                    ID = re.WordID.ToString(),
                    Original = re.Word.Original,
                    Translate = re.Word.Translation,
                    Result = re.Result
                }).ToArray()
            }).ToArray();
```

Ошибка:

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Core.Dto.WordDto[]
>   ToArrayWordDto
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: IMHO, `.AsEnumerable()` после `.GroupBy(r => r.Date)`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Спасибо, можете рассказать, что дает это метод ?

Comment: @Jitsu AsEnumerable превращает следующий селект в вызов Enumerable.Select, который, при выполнении ToArray ниже, начинает перебирать объекты из результата GroupBy по одному, превращая их в ReportDto. Без вызова AsEnumerable ваш Select остается Queryable.Select, который не перебирает объекты, а просто добавляет вызов Select к дереву запроса. Которое LINQ to Entities пытается отразить в SQL и выполнить на стороне SQL Server. И не может (по разным причинам, но в этом случае - потому что не осиливает ваш запрос.

Comment: @Jitsu TLDR все до AsEnumerable выполняется на базе, после - в памяти.

Comment: Ну так оформите ответ, %кто-нибудь%!

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо за пояснение

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ReportDto
{
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public WordDto[] Words { get; set; }
}
 ReportDto[] qwe = this.context.TestResults
        .Where(r => r.Word.Vocabulary.VocabularyID == id)
        .GroupBy(r => r.Date)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(r => new ReportDto
        {
            Date = r.Key,
            Words = r.Select(re => new WordDto
            {
                ID = re.WordID.ToString(),
                Original = re.Word.Original,
                Translate = re.Word.Translation,
                Result = re.Result
            }).ToArray()
        }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблема в первом toarray(). IQeryable работает с деревьями выражений и просто не может его прожевать.

Answer (score -1):

```
    ReportDto[] qwe = (from elem in this.context.TestResults
                       where elem.Word.Vocabulary.VacabularyID == id
                       group elem by elem.Date into groupElem
                       select new ReportDto
                       {
                           Date = groupElem.Key,
                           Words = (from w_elem in groupElem.AsEnumerable()
                                    select new WordDto
                                    {
                                        ID = w_elem.WordID.ToString(),
                                        Original = w_elem.Word.Original,
                                        Translate = w_elem.Word.Translation,
                                        Result = w_elem.Result
                                    }).ToArray()
                       }).ToArray();
```

Однако подозреваю, что необходимо: 
`Words = (from w_elem in groupElem.Value.AsEnumerable()`